# changing the font_name of OneLineListItem MDList

Tags: python, fonts, widget, kivy, kivymd

I would like to change the font_name of OneLineListItem in the MDList in kivymd. The changes will happen after loading a screen.

Comment: I have not tried this, but have a look at the [theming documentation](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/0.104.1/themes/theming/index.html#kivymd.theming.ThemeManager.font_styles)

Comment: I changed the font in different widget, but it didn't work with MDList.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivymd.app import MDApp

KV = '''
OneLineListItem:
    text: "[font=JetBrainsMono-ExtraBold-Italic.ttf]One-line item with avatar[/font]"

'''


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


MainApp().run()
```